# Тормозит android смартфон и быстро расходуется батарея

Tags: android

Дело в том, что у меня на смартфоне установлено около 230 приложений.
После этого, Android начинает сильно тормозит и с трудом делает даже элементарные операции свайпа в оболочке и даже простое включение экрана и камеры у него вызывают нехилые затрюднения.
Помимо этого, очень быстро расходуется батарея - заряд заканчивается за 5 часов в режиме полного неиспользования, но с включенной передачей мобильных данных.
Если же отключить передачу мобильных данных смартфон способен работать более двух дней.
После полного сброса аппарата все приходит в норму и всё начинает работать адекватно, как и в первый день.

У меня установлено приложение KillApps, которое показывает активными более 85 приложений в течении пяти часов работы смартфона (без активного его использования).
В начале использования смартфона все приложения из памяти были заблаговременно закрыты через эту программу.
Воспользовалтся за это время я примерно 5-6 приложениям.

Хотел бы задать вопрос к тем, кто разбирается во внутренних кишках работы ОС Android.
Я не понимаю причину, почему андроид такое себе позволяет?
Почему ненужные мне в данный момент приложения (около 90%) жрут мою оперативную память, время процессора, интернет трафик и заряд батареи?

Comment: PS Столько много приложений было установлено специально, в качестве эксперимента, т.к. заметил, что через какое-тов время использования смартфона он начинает работать всё хуже и хуже, а очистка от мусора и кеша никак не помогала.
Теперь понимаю почему так происходит, но не понимаю, зачем так сделано.

Comment: Очистка от мусора и кэша программами вроде Clean Master?  Не используйте их. Они чистят системный кэш, который необходим системе для быстродействия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Помимо этого, очень быстро расходуется батарея - заряд заканчивается за 5 часов в режиме полного неиспользования, но с включенной передачей мобильных данных. Если же отключить передачу мобильных данных смартфон способен работать более двух дней.

Приложения (230 штук!!) качают в фоне рекламу и не только. Батарея садится из-за постоянного залаза в сеть. Попробуйте отключить фоновую передачу данных (на Cyanogenmod это делается так: Настройки > Передача данных > Меню > Ограничить фоновый режим.

Answer (score 3):

Это всё работает примерно так:

1. Все почти приложения ходят в сеть в фоновом режиме после их запуска первого.
2. Они в фоне принимают и отправляют данные на сервера. Контент загружают, статистику отправляют, рекламу грузят.
3. Остановить это можно только через принудительную остановку приложения. После этого они не имеют возможности что-то делать пока их снова не запустят.
4. Сделано так не случайно - юзер должен иметь возможность всегда иметь возможность видеть в приложениях актуальную информацию, а разработчик должен иметь возможность эти данные на девайс загрузить.

Вывод - всё так и задумано. Чтобы с этим бороться надо выключать принудительно конкретные приложения вручную или силами специальных приложений.

Comment: Это я понимаю. Но держать в памяти 90% приложений, которых я даже не запускал с времени включения смартфона - здесь есть что-то глубоко неправильное в самой архитектуре ОС.

Comment: @АбдулаРамазанов,  есть такое оповещение об окончании загрузки системы (после включения) и приложения, однажды запущенные когда-то в прошлом, подписавшись на на это оповещение запускаются уже без Вашего участия

Answer (score 1):

Ставь кастомную прошивку и будет тебе счастье, а вообще, вы форумом ошиблись